# Can’t log in to the Craft control panel

Tags: admin, csrf, environmentvariables

After I input my credentials, it just stayed on the login page, and did not go to the dashboard. The password is good, we didn't get invalid username and password error.

I opened the trace mode and found this error in the craft.log:

> Unable to determine if PATH_INFO is enabled on the server: [curl] 60:
>   Could it cause the error?
>
> The CSRF token could not be verified

```
2016/12/20 12:52:41 [error] [exception.Craft\HttpException.400] exception 'Craft\HttpException' with message 'The CSRF token could not be verified.' in /var/www/vhosts/xxx.com/master/craft/app/services/HttpRequestService.php:1314 Stack trace:
    #0 /var/www/vhosts/xxx.com/master/craft/app/framework/base/CComponent.php(561): Craft\HttpRequestService->validateCsrfToken(Object(CEvent))
    #1 /var/www/vhosts/xxx.com/master/craft/app/framework/base/CApplication.php(212): CComponent->raiseEvent('onBeginRequest', Object(CEvent))
    #2 /var/www/vhosts/xxx.com/master/craft/app/framework/base/CApplication.php(183): CApplication->onBeginRequest(Object(CEvent))
    #3 /var/www/vhosts/xxx.com/master/craft/app/index.php(62): CApplication->run()
    #4 /var/www/vhosts/xxx.com/master/public/index.php(20): require_once('/var/www/vhosts...')
    #5 {main} REQUEST_URI=/wtuygyq/upuj/duhuhog
```

Comment: Did this happen just once or do you have this problem often. With which browser did this happen and did you try other browsers?

Comment: It has been 2 days from IE and chrome. I cleared runtime, restart httpd. Doesn't help.

Comment: `#5 {main} REQUEST_URI=/wtuygyq/upuj/duhuhog` - is that request uri real, or did you obfuscate it?

Comment: I did't change REQUEST_URI , I am also wondering what it is? Some decryption issue?

Comment: I think it's a bot making random posts your site and the real reason you can't log in is somewhere else in your logs.  I'd nuke the log files and try to load in again to get rid of the extra logging noise.

Comment: @BradBell  I copied production db and code to dev, everything works properly. what's wrong with my prd environment.